# Mock mailBox by GreenMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I try to mock server with mailbox to test mail send by another apllication.
I try to use GreenMail. I want to my test received mail send from some apllication.
 This is my code in test:` ServerSetup setup = new ServerSetup(3025, "localhost", "smtp");

```
    GreenMail greenMail = new GreenMail(setup);
    greenMail.setUser("user1@mail.com", "user1", "user1");
    greenMail.start();


    greenMail.waitForIncomingEmail(50000, 1);
    Message[] messages = greenMail.getReceivedMessages();

    try {
        System.out.println(messages[0].getSubject());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

I run this code and send mail from my personal mailbox to adress "user1@mail.com". And mail doesn't reaches. Sombody know what I do wrong ?Please for help. Maybe i should use another tool for what I want achieve ?

Comment: How exactly are you sending the message?  Are you using JavaMail?  Have you configured it to use host localhost and port 3025 to reach the server?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: @Bill Shannon . I run my code, next I send from mail to user1@mail.com from my gmail account. i don't configured port 3025 - it could be problem ? In output there is only exception when I want to get first element from messages array. I just need check mail content from mail send by application in my functional automated test. Maybe I chose wrong way ?

Comment: That will never work.  Gmail will never know how to route the message to your fake test server.  This is only going to work if you configure a mail client (JavaMail, Thunderbird, etc.) to connect directly to your fake test server when sending messages.

Comment: @Bill Shannon - Thanks.  if I can't configure a mail client in application, I never test like that ? So how I can test mail send by application ?

Comment: What application?  You need to configure the application to use the host and port that your test server is running on.